# Calculate density operator on hands-on example

Tags: homework-and-exercises, density-operator

In my assignments the density operator is given as follows:

$$\rho = \sum_{\alpha = 1}^{6} w_\alpha |\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|\quad \text{where}\quad w = \left(\dfrac{1}{10},\dfrac{1}{10},\dfrac{1}{10},\dfrac{1}{10},\dfrac{1}{10},\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$

Calculating this thing seems trivial, but expanding the formula, I'd get:

$$\dfrac{1}{10}|1\rangle\langle 1| + \dfrac{1}{10}|2\rangle\langle 2| + \dfrac{1}{10}|3\rangle\langle 3| + \dfrac{1}{10}|4\rangle\langle 4| + \dfrac{1}{10}|5\rangle\langle 5| + \dfrac{1}{2}|6\rangle\langle 6|$$

which is a really long term. Is there any way condensing it to a single matrix? Also there is nowhere written to which dimension the states $|\alpha\rangle$ belong. But probably I'm missing a general property.

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got? I assume your states $|\alpha\rangle$ are orthogonal to each other, correct? Then it's a diagonal density matrix in the $|\alpha\rangle$-basis with $\omega_\alpha$ along the main diagonal.

Comment: Well, I got to calculate the von Neumann entropy $S = -k\,\mathrm{tr}(\rho \,\ln(\rho))$ which should collapse to a single value, but not with the formulation I came up with. What you mentioned seems promising: When orthogonal $\mathrm{tr}(w_\alpha\,|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|) = w_\alpha$ ?

Comment: For von Neumann entropy, if you want to avoid taking the logarithm of a matrix, you can simply apply the formula to the eigenvalues of the matrix $-k\sum_i p_i \ln p_i$ for eigenvalues $p_i$. For any states, by cyclicity of the trace, $tr(x|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|)=\langle\phi|x|\psi\rangle$. Your "$x$" is a scalar here, $\omega_\alpha$, so you should be able to do the rest